# ServiceStack Identity on field other than PK - Insert fails

Tags: sql-server, servicestack, sql-server-identity

When I try to use the "Insert" function in ServiceStack (against SQL Server 2014) using an object from the below class, it tries to insert a 0 (default of the ContactId property) for the ContactId instead of auto generating one in the database. ContactId is `IDENTITY NOT NULL`. ContactId is the clustered index, but GlobalContactId is the nonclusted primary key.

```
[Alias("Contact")]
[Schema("Customer")]
public partial class Contact
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Guid GlobalContactId { get; set; }
    [AutoIncrement]
    public int ContactId { get; set;}
     ...
```

I'm doing this because:

1. It's a distributed application, and needs to phone home - hence the guid
2. It's an import of old data and its easier for users to reference an int rather than a guid (at least for their specific location), and they will want to continue with that moving forward
3. I'm using the ContactId as a FK to other tables whose data doesn't phone home for performance reasons

I would have thought that if a property has `[AutoIncrement]` and the value matches the default for that type then it would assume the value was not set.

**Edit**

For now I'm just reverting to using ContactId as both PK and identity, and adding the uniqueidentifier with a unique check constraint

Comment: possible duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277431/servicestack-ormlite-cannot-update-identity-column

Comment: Not a duplicate. That question was in regards to the PK of the table having autoincrement - which I know how to handle. In this case, the identity field isn't the primary key.

Comment: Probably this can help. http://techfunda.com/howto/121/auto-increment-property-in-model

Comment: @AlexKudryashev The attributes I'm using are specific to ServiceStack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OrmLite the `[AutoIncrement]` attribute is for specifying an Auto Incrementing primary key. So it can't be be used on a non-Primary Key column.